# Error retorna NULL

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy consultando una base de datos (Mongodb) el cual busca un `user` por su `email` y al momento de no existir en dicha base de datos, me debería retornar un error, pero la variable `err` (al consultar con un console.log) solo devuelve `null`, exista o no exista el usuario en la base de datos. El código es el siguiente:

```javascript
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
const User = require('../models/user')
const jwt = require('../services/jwt')

const login = (req, res) => {
    const params = req.body
    const email = params.email.toLowerCase()
    const password = params.password

    User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                status: 500,
                message: 'No existe el usuario',
            })
        } else {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, check) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        status: 500,
                        message: 'Error al servidor',
                    })
                } else if (!check) {
                    res.status(401).json({
                        status: 401,
                        message: 'La contraseña es incorrecta',
                    })
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        status: 200,
                        accessToken: jwt.createAccessToken(user),
                        refreshToken: jwt.createRefreshToken(user),
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Al enviar la solicitud por **Postman**, envió lo siguiente (el email no existe en la base de datos):

```json
{
    "email": "alvarez97@gmail.com",
    "password": ""
}
```

y el server, me retorna lo siguiente:

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

Comment: Tienes `User` definido para el modelo, pero usas `user.password` para comparar la contraseña. Creo que debería ser `User.password`

Comment: @Triby, no es ese el problema, puedes leer mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400706/error-retorna-null/400781#400781). El OP está atacando mal las posibles respuestas del método `findOne`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea verificar la existencia de un documento en una colección de MongoDB usando el método [`findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com).

Sin embargo al realizar la consulta, enviando un valor `email` que de antemano sabemos que no existe, obtenemos el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple. Sucede que al consultar una colección de MongoDB usando cualquiera de los métodos `find()` o `findOne`, podemos tener 3 resultados y tú solo estás evaluando 2.

Los tres resultados posibles son:

1. Error en la consulta
2. No se encontró ninguna coincidencia
3. Se encontró una coincidencia (o más si se usa el método `find()`)

Y resulta que estás obviando el punto número 2, que es precisamente lo que sucede cuando consultas por el campo `email` pasando como valor uno que no existe en la DB.

Lo que debes hacer es escribir el caso particular en que la consulta devuelve un valor de `user` como `null`.

El error en consola indica que no se puede leer la propiedad `password` de `null` y es precisamente porque la consulta no encuentra coincidencias.

El código lo deberías reescribir a algo como:

```js
User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
  // verificamos caso 1: Error en la consulta
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ // <- devolvemos con return
      status: 500,
      message: 'Error de servidor', // <- es un error de consulta
    });
  }
  // verificamos caso 2: No hay coincidencias
  if(!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({ // <- devolvemos con return y 404 Not Found
      status: 404,
      message: 'No existe usuario', // <- no hay resultados
    });
  }
  // resto de operaciones en caso que si exista el usuario
}
```

El valor de `error` (si está presente) indica un problema de conexión con el Servidor MongoDB, no indica que no existan resultados, eso debes tener siempre en cuenta cuando trabajas con MongoDB y Mongoose.

Un resultado de una consulta puede ser `null` cuando no se encuentran coincidencias o una lista vacía (cuando se usa `find()` y no se encuentran coincidencias).

Por lo tanto la forma de verificar que una consulta ha devuelto un resultado es analizando si el objeto (`user` en este caso) devuelto es distinto de `null`, `undefined` o es distinto de una lista vacía.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: ¡Excelente! no sabía lo de los 3 resultados posibles, muchas gracias!